# recognize python in env

Tags: path, virtualenv, python-3.8

I make env
by pipenv install
and I join env
by pipenv shell

I got some troubles in pipenv shell with no module error.
so I did many trials.
and I find something wrong.

[image]
this is the status in my local PC.
when I type python3, it export the path in the virtual env.

[image]
this is the web server has troubles.
when I type python3, it export the path outside of the virtual env.

what's the matter and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `alias` overriding the `python3` command in the ec2 instance.

Try the following command:
`pipenv run python3`

Comment: try the command 'pipenv run python3' in the virtual env?? or outside of the virtual env? anyway, Though I tried both of them, there are nothing changed T.T

Comment: and this is my bashrc alias. alias python3="/usr/local/bin/python3.8"
alias pip3="/usr/local/bin/pip3.8"